# GetGlue api total number of check-ins

Tags: api

Get glue API provides with a method to get list of check ins

http://api.getglue.com/v2/object/users?objectId=movies/slumdog_millionaire/danny_boyle&action=checkedIn

Strangely enough I can't find the method that provides the total number of check-ins(4109 in this case) which is available on the page:

http://getglue.com/movies/slumdog_millionaire/danny_boyle

I hope I'm not going to have to retrieve the HTML page and parse it do I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering it myself, I was too fast asking it. However in case anybody is wondering,

http://api.getglue.com/v2/object/get?objectId=movies/slumdog_millionaire/danny_boyle&oauth_consumer_key=[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]

Where objectId is getGlue recognized object id and oauth_consumer_key is your consumer key that you may get from getGlue after emailing them.

Will return the information that I searched (including number of check-ins). Funny enough check ins is not included in the sample response listed on the GetGlue API page for /object/get method, I don't understand why.